# How to avoid Using Filesort in "!=" mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Please, help me!
How to optimize a query like:

```
SELECT idu
FROM `user`
WHERE `username`!='manager'
  AND `username`!='user1@yahoo.com'
ORDER BY lastdate DESC
```

This is the explain:

```
explain SELECT idu FROM `user` WHERE `username`!='manager' AND `username`!='ser1@yahoo.com' order by lastdate DESC;
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys              | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user  | ALL  | username,username-lastdate | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 208478 | Using where; Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To avoid file sorting in a big database.

Comment: Is there an index on `username`?

Comment: in case of " != " - index cannot be used.

Comment: It might help to index `lastdate`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this query is just scanning all rows, you need an index on `lastdate` to avoid MySQL from having to order the results manually (using filesort, which isn't always to disk/temp table).

For super read performance, add the following multi-column "covering" index:

```
user(lastdate, username, idu)
```

A "covering" index would allow MySQL to just scan the index instead of the actual table data.

If using InnoDB and any of the above columns are your primary key, you don't need it in the index.